# OrientDB - Create case insensitive index during import CSV

Tags: csv, indexing, import, orientdb

Is there any way to create a case insensitive index during import in orientdb?

Here's my current json for import:

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "/tmp/data.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {} },
  "transformers": [
    { "vertex": { "class": "User" } }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "remote:/opt/orientdb/databases/MyData",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "classes": [
         {"name": "User", "extends": "V"},
       ], "indexes": [
         {"class":"User", "fields":["id:Long"], "type":"UNIQUE" },
         {"class":"User", "fields":["email:String"], "type":"NOTUNIQUE" }
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want the email to be a case-insensitive index.  I've tried metadata I'm not sure the format, I know if I create an index with "COLLATE ci" that'll give me case insensitive, but I want this to be created during import.  All documents and questions/answers point to collate ci but nothing about how to set it during import.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

at the moment ETL doesn't allow to set collate to the index. 
To have more control over the schema creation, you can use LOAD SCRIPT before launching ETL.

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Load-Script.html

```
$ORIENTDB_HOME/bin/console.sh "CONNECT REMOTE:localhost/demo;LOAD SCRIPT /path/to/scripts/data.osql"
```

and then

```
$ORIENTDB_HOME/bin/oetl.sh $(pwd)/etl-config.json
```